# splash activity delay time depend on process

Tags: android

I have write a splash activity as I search like this

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity{
private Utility utility;
private static final long SPLASH_TIME = 2000;
private Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    context = this;
    utility = Utility.getInstance();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            utility.fillDatabase(context);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME);
}
}
```

as you can see I have utility.fillDatabase() in my run method and my delay time is 2 second but I need to rewrite my splash activity finish after all of task was done not after specific time. please help me to make an idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) .

Do your job at [doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29)  -`utility.fillDatabase(context);`

And hide / finish the splash only at [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29)